# Using Mocks When Testing Nested Redux Reducers

Tags: testing, mocking, redux, reducers

When testing redux reducers that delegate to other reducers, should I be mocking out the delegated reducers?

For example, in my *step* reducer I delegate to a `filters` reducer:

```
case SELECT_FILTER_REQUEST: {
  return {
    ...state,
    filters: filters(state.filters, action),
  };
}
```

Should I be mocking `filters` here?